# Making sure at least 1 of 40+ radio buttons is checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery.validate form form validation. The problem is there are about 40 radio inputs on the form, `s1_AM`, `s1_PM`, `s2_AM`, `s2_PM`, each with about 10ish `radio` inputs apiece. At least one of the four options has to be checked, but not all four. If I put `class="required"` in the code, it is not correct, since it makes all four options required. How do I get around this?

Ideally id like to keep the validation the way it is, but add an alert if a radio is empty.

The jQuery

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
$("#enroll").validate({
invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
        var message = errors == 1
            ? 'You missed 1 required field'
            : 'You missed ' + errors + ' required fields';
        $("div.Error span").html(message);
        $("div.Error").show();
    } else {
        $("div.Error").hide();
    }
}
});
```

The radios are dynamic btw:

```
if($row['s1_AM_fill'] < $row['s1_AM_cap']) {
   $s1_AM .= '<input type="radio" name="s1_AM" id="s1_AM_'.$id.'" value="'.$id.'" />;
}
```

Plus three more, for `s1_PM`, `s2_AM` and `s2_PM`.

Here's what I did, except once the alert starts, it doesn't stop

```
$('#submit').click(function () {$("ul.courses").each(function(){
  $(this).find("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
    alert("You must select at least 1 available course");
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Please show your rendered HTML... not all 40 inputs, but enough to formulate a concise demo.  Also, please better explain what you want... are all 40 inputs in the same group (same `name`)?  etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use additional `submit` or `click` handler functions which only have the potential to interfere with the plugin's built-in event handlers.

You simply create a new rule by using the [plugin's built-in `addMethod()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod).  Something like this...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('customrule', function() {
    return ($("input[name='s1_AM']:checked").val() || $("input[name='s1_PM']:checked").val() || $("input[name='s2_AM']:checked").val() || $("input[name='s2_PM']:checked").val());
}, 'Please select from at least one group' );
```

The new rule checks to see if at least one of your four `radio` groups is used.  The rule is applied as follows...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#enroll').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            's1_AM': {
                customrule: true
            },
            's1_PM': {
                customrule: true
            },
            's2_AM': {
                customrule: true
            },
            's2_PM': {
                customrule: true
            }
        },
        groups: { // use this option to consolidate the four messages into one
            groupname: "s1_AM s1_PM s2_AM s2_PM"
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/93jTZ/**

You'll need to adjust the error placement functions as per your own project's specifications.

Other options:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions